# Best practice to write Python exception in a log file

Tags: python, logging

I defined a `log_text()` function to print custom messages and write it in a log file. My project architecture is quite simple, with the main script calling functions from another file:

```
main.py
|
|--- functions.py -- log_text()
```

I would like to catch any Python exception and print them in the log file, to help future users. For now I embedded almost all operations of main in a try/except block like this:

```
import #...
class parameters():
  log_file_path = #path to the log file

prm = parameters()

try:
  #main code

except Exception as e:
  log_text(log_file_path, e)
  print(e)
```

I am used to do this for small portions of a code, but not the whole script like that. Is it the common practice? Is there a better way to write any exception to a log file?

Comment: Thanks @Im Groot, this is what I have done, as stated in my question. But is it common practice for bigger scripts?

Comment: This seems fine. Note, though, that if you let the interpreter exit with a traceback, your script has a non-zero exit status. If you simply catch the exception and let the interpreter exit "normally" after logging the exception, your script will have a zero exit status. You probably want to put an explicit `sys.exit(1)` following `print(e)`, or even just reraise the same exception after logging it, by replacing `print(e)` with `raise`.

Comment: @jeannej .Not for bigger scripts, it makes the code less readable and harder to maintain, especially if the main code block is large, oftenly.

Comment: @ImGroot what would be the practice for bigger scripts then?

Comment: @ImGroot That's easily accommodated by defining a single `main` function to be called, rather than having a large module-level series of statements. (Plus, that makes testing easier, as you can simply import the "script" and test `main`.)

Comment: Thank you @chepner. Would you like to propose it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine, for the most part. To keep things simpler, I would define a single function that can be called in your `try` statement. (This function can allow for testing, as you can import your script and call the function under controlled circumstances.) If you aren't actually "handling" the exception, you should also either re-raise the exception, or explicitly terminate the script with a non-zero exit status so that the caller still knows there was an error.

```
def main():
   ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        log_test(log_file_path, e)
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)
```

To re-raise the exception, replace both `print(e)` and `sys.exit(1)` with a single `raise` statement.